# Monitor dir content and add files to list

Tags: python, list, directory, monitoring

There is a server, into which a .csv file is pulled every 15s. Once every few days I want to read in all the new .csv files and append the data into a .h5 file. I've got all that part working quite well, wheat I'm missing is an efficient way of defining what files to look at. At the moment I run:

```
all_files = []
root = "//server/dir/"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(network_location):
    for name in files:
        all_files.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

where the directory has this structure:

```
year
 ¦ 
 months ...
  ¦ 
  days ...
```

This now contains data since February and the os.walk() is taking quite long. Is there a way to make it only go across the files that are not in `all_files`?

I've had a look at `watchdog` but don't quite understand how to make it work for this case. Are there any other packages or approaches? `all_files` should just be a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

**simple version:**
the directory has this structure:

```
tmp  
  ¦  
  file1.txt  
  file2.txt
```

Code:

```
import os
dir_path = r'E:\download\tmp'
only_file=[dir_path+'\\'+name for name in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(dir_path+'\\'+name) ]
only_file
```

Output:
['E:\download\tmp\file1.txt', 'E:\download\tmp\file2.txt']

**complete version:**
the directory has this structure:

```
tmp\2017\1\1\
  - 20170101_1.txt'
  - 20170101_2.txt'
tmp\2017\1\2\
  - 20170102_1.txt'
  - 20170102_2.txt'
```

**method1:**
Code:

```
import os
dir_path = r'E:\download\tmp'
file_list=[]
for dirPath, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(dir_path):
    for f in fileNames:
        file_list.append(os.path.join(dirPath, f))
file_list
```

Output:

```
['E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\1\\20170101_1.txt',
 'E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\1\\20170101_2.txt',
 'E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\2\\20170102_1.txt',
 'E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\2\\20170102_2.txt']
```

**method2:**

Code:

```
import os
file_list=[]
dir_path = r'E:\download\tmp'
only_dir_year=[dir_path+'\\'+name for name in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isdir(dir_path+'\\'+name) ]
for year_dir in only_dir_year:
    only_dir_month=[year_dir+'\\'+name for name in os.listdir(year_dir) if os.path.isdir(year_dir+'\\'+name) ]
    for month_dir in only_dir_month:
        only_dir_day=[month_dir+'\\'+name for name in os.listdir(month_dir) if os.path.isdir(month_dir+'\\'+name) ]
for day_dir in only_dir_day:
    tmp=[day_dir+'\\'+name for name in os.listdir(day_dir) if os.path.isfile(day_dir+'\\'+name) ]
    file_list=file_list+tmp
file_list
```

Output:

```
['E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\1\\20170101_1.txt',
 'E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\1\\20170101_2.txt',
 'E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\2\\20170102_1.txt',
 'E:\\download\\tmp\\2017\\1\\2\\20170102_2.txt']
```

Comment: While i appreciate the effort, I'm afraid method 1 is what I have, and that is the problem. It walks through the whole dir, not just the new files.